# 4TB from HDD1 to HDD2 - usb3.0 hdd docking station - dual bay or two single bay?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, speed, usb-3, docking-station

right now I'm transferring 4TB of files from HDD1 to HDD2 both connected to the same dual bay usb 3.0 docking station (specifically [this](https://www.inateck.com/fd2102.html) one). The file manager of my pc says "approx. 9 hours left".

It happens I have two identical dual bay usb 3.0 docking station. Would it be faster if I connect HDD1 to dock1 and HDD2 to dock2, and connect the two docks to two different usb3.0 ports?

Thanks

Comment: I can't say for sure given that I don't have experience with this docking station, but it may be optimized enough to not make any difference. If the dock is smart enough and filter out communication over the USB line, then it is definitely going to be slower if you use 2 docks.

Comment: Your transfer speed is about 123MB/s, which might well be the maximum throughput of the drives. It is well below the maximum throughput for USB 3.0.

Comment: @mtak so?  Wouldn't it change due to HDD bottlenecks?

Comment: How would the drives become faster when you put them in separate docking stations?